# Django: Refactoring template view to include count?

Tags: django

TEMPLATE:

```
 <ul id="bugs-list">
  {% for group in groups %}

      <h2>{{ group.name }}</h2> <span></span>
      {% for data in group.grab_bugs %}
          <li><a href="{{data.get_absolute_url}}">{{data.name }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}

  {% endfor %}

  </ul>
```

models.py:

```
class BrowserGroups( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=100 )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    browsers = models.ManyToManyField( 'Browser' )

    def grab_bugs(self):
        bugs = Bug.objects.filter(browser__browsergroups=self,really_bug=True).distinct()
        return bugs

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Browser Groups'
```

I'm trying to render the number of bugs (`data`) near the `<h2>`. What would be an efficient way of including the count of `data` near the h2? Should I define a separate function in my model class to return the total # of bugs? Or is there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% with group.grab_bugs as distinct_bugs %}
    <h2>{{ group.name }}</h2> (Count: {{ distinct_bugs.count }})
    {% for data in distinct_bugs %}
        <li><a href="{{data.get_absolute_url}}">{{data.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Explanation: the `grab_bugs` method of the `Group` class returns a querset of `Bug` instances. To get a count of the bugs invoke the `count()` method on the queryset.

This will cost you two queries (not counting the ones inside the loop). One to get the count and then next to retrieve a list of bugs.

Comment: Is that syntactically correct? I could've sworn you can't have invocation parentheses in there, `()`. `.count` works.

Comment: @meder: GRRRR. typo :P Changed it :)

Comment: One other thing - since I'm calling the `grab_bugs` function twice now, is it less efficient?